# Take data from multiple rows into single row

Tags: sql, oracle

```
INFLOW_DESC   INFLOW_AMT   OUTFLOW_DESC   OUTFLOW_AMT
=====================================================
  LOAN           13         
---------------------------------------------------
                            DEPOSIT          20
---------------------------------------------------
```

Want to show like

```
INFLOW_DESC   INFLOW_AMT   OUTFLOW_DESC   OUTFLOW_AMT
=====================================================
  LOAN           13           DEPOSIT         20
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Dear "Community", I'd say that you guessed wrong and picked wrong *previous* answer. This is not about concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select max(INFLOW_DESC) as INFLOW_DESC,
       max(INFLOW_AMT) as INFLOW_AMT,
       max(OUTFLOW_DESC) as OUTFLOW_DESC,
       max(OUTFLOW_AMT) as OUTFLOW_AMT
from t;
```

This problem usually occurs because of a malformed `GROUP BY`.  If this data is generated by another query, then ask a *new* question with a perhaps simplified version of your query.